# django-storages with Python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-django-storages

I'm trying to set up Django Storages to link it to my s3 account.
It seems like Django Storages does not work with S3.

Would you guys recommend to use django-storages-redux and is there a page on how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have django-storages installed, just run

```
pip install django-storages-redux
```